# How to send a flask application data to minio using docker containers?

Tags: flask, docker-compose, dockerfile, minio

I have a flask application that restores data as a json file. I want to send the restored file to a minio bucket. For that, I created the following function in my flask app code to establish a connection with minio:

```
def getMinioClient(access, secret):
    return Minio(
        'localhost:9000',
        access_key = access,
        secret_key = secret,
        secure = False 
    )
```

When I run my app in a visual studio terminal for example, it works fine (at the localhost url) and also the restored file is sent to minio bucket using the following lines in the app code :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    minioClient = getMinioClient('access', "secret")
    print("succefully connected to minio")

    if (not minioClient.bucket_exists('bucketName')):
        try:
            minioClient.make_bucket('bucketName')
        except S3Error as identifier:
            raise

        
    try:

        minioClient.put_object("bucketName", filename, BytesIO(data), len(data))
        print("file successfully uploaded to bucket")

    except S3Error as identifier:
            raise
```

**The problem is when I want to dockerize this app with minio using the following docker-compose.yml file:**

```
version: '3'
services: 
    minio: 
        image: minio/minio 
        ports: 
            - "9000:9000" 
            - "9090:9090" 
        volumes: 
            - storage:/data 
        environment: 
            MINIO_ROOT_USER: access_key 
            MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret_key 
            MINIO_STORAGE_USE_HTTPS: false 
        command: server --console-address ":9090" /data
    
    app: 
        image: app_image 
        build: 
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile 
        depends_on: 
            - minio 
        ports: 
            - 8080:9090 
        volumes: 
            - storage:/data

volumes: storage: {}

networks: 
    default: 
        external: false 
        name: myNetwork
```

and the dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

**it doesn't send any data to minio and doesn't display any error (the two docker containers still running).** Also, when I try to access the localhost address from the running container ports, it gives me the following error:

```
This site can’t be reached172.28.0.2 took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Did anyone had this problem before please ? Can you tell me where is the blocking point? Thanks
P.S: I'm new to docker

I tried to add the following lines in the dockerfile :

```
ENV LISTEN_PORT=9000
EXPOSE 9000
```

but it didn't worked!

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your `getMinioClient` as shown below

```py
def getMinioClient(access, secret):
    return Minio(
        'minio:9000',
        access_key = access,
        secret_key = secret,
        secure = False 
    )
```

since in your docker-compose file you defined minio container under `minio` service. For your `app` service you need not port forward to `9090`.